# Do xgboost and random forests in general handle multiple splits of the same numeric feature in a single branch?

Tags: random-forest, decision-trees, xgboost

For example, let's say that the age (say $x$) of a person for $12< x< 25$ can be used to predict computer usage to a high degree of certainty. In a decision tree, this could be represented by a split of $x<25$ followed by a split of $x>12$.

Does xgboost, or other decision tree learning algorithms in general, handle multiple splits within the same branch?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/10713/55122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can handle multiple splits withing the same branch.
A decision tree model can use the same feature as many times as optimally needed.
You can see an example in the [sklearn doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html).
The petal-length feature is used multiple times in the same branch.