# Does Gradient Boosting perform n-ary splits where n > 2?

Tags: xgboost, gbm, lightgbm, natural-gradient-boosting, catboost

I wonder whether algorithms such as GBM, XGBoost, CatBoost, and LightGBM perform more than two splits at a node in the decision trees? Can a node be split into 3 or more branches instead of merely binary splits? Can more than one feature be used in deciding how to split a node? Can a feature be re-used in splitting a descendant node?

Comment: Your question needs more focus: the last two questions are sufficiently different from the title question that they should be asked separately.  And indeed those have already been asked, e.g. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/60848/55122 and https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/10713/55122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradient boosting can be applied to any base model, so doing it with a Quinlan-family decision tree (which allow for such higher-arity splits for categorical features) should make this possible.  However, all implementations of gradient boosted trees that I know of (and certainly XGBoost, CatBoost, LightGBM) all use CART as their tree model, so you won't get anything but binary trees.  (These GBMs do modify CART a little, e.g. in using histogram binning to reduce the split searches, but nothing as drastic as n-ary splits for categoricals.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Why are the limitations put into place? Won't it be more accurate and flexible to do away with such limitations? Should I try implementing my own gradient boosting regressor that can perform n-ary splits, use more than one feature at a split, and reuse features?

Comment: "More accurate and flexible" on the training set might overfit, so it's not an obvious improvement.  multivariate splits and n-ary splits for continuous variables will hurt training time, as well; but if you build such a thing and can show improvement on some benchmark datasets, maybe that can be overcome.  Reusing features is already standard.

Comment: It suddenly occurred to me that there is no point in doing a ternary split as it can always be done in two-level binary splits. As for multivariate splits, I think it is worth looking into. I suppose reusing features in the descendants of a decision tree has been the standard in the implementations of regressors.